# How can i do paging on mvc3 gridview by only fetching each time 10 rows from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, razor

Below i have fetched the datasource Model.slst as it contains around 1000 rows but it is too slow as 1000 rows should be fetched on each time so i want to fetched only 10 rows on each paging but i have no idea how to do it.

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model.slst, rowsPerPage: 10, canPage: false, canSort: true,ajaxUpdateContainerId: "lgrid");
 }

           <h3>Services</h3>
            @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "lgrid",
                headerStyle: "head",
                alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("S.N.", format: @<text>@{count++;}@count</text>, style: "sn"),
                grid.Column("Services", format: @<text>@item.ServiceName</text>),
                grid.Column("Edit", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditServices",
                         new { id = item.ServiceId }, new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "emailDialog", data_dialog_title = "Edit" })),
                         grid.Column("Delete", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteServices", new { id = item.ServiceId }, new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "emailDialog", data_dialog_title = "Delete" }))
                         ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MSDN article that illustrates what you want: 
 [Get the Most out of WebGrid in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) or [Efficient Paging with WebGrid Web Helper](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=618)

Comment: 'with regards to my requirement i think i need to count paging in sqlserver and send it to front end  and by using jquery i have to fetched the row' but still i am not getting any clear path. Thankyou for you comment but i thought that proccess is long'